# MongoDB : How to sort documents by array field?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, sorting

I need to sort documents by an array field containing boolean values.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610024d989c5b829e72940c5"),
    "firstname" : "Christophe",
    "lastname" : "Pichon",
    "documents" : [
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024d90053e800143b0fd3",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024d90053e800143b0fd5",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "60fea9140053e800143b0f92",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : false,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024d90053e800143b0fd7",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610024b189c5b829e72940c4"),
    "firstname" : "Paulette",
    "lastname" : "Besnard",
    "documents" : [
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024b00053e800143b0fc4",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : true
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024b10053e800143b0fc6",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "60fea9140053e800143b0f92",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : false,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "610024b10053e800143b0fc8",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60febc9e89c5b829e72940c3"),
    "firstname" : "Louis",
    "lastname" : "Herve",
    "documents" : [
        {
            "mongoId" : "60febc9e0053e800143b0fb7",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : true
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "60febc9e0053e800143b0fb9",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : true
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "60fea9140053e800143b0f92",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : false,
            "signed" : false
        },
        {
            "mongoId" : "60febc9e0053e800143b0fbb",
            "status" : "notified",
            "signable" : true,
            "signed" : false
        }
    ]
},
```

Once sorted, I need this result :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60febc9e89c5b829e72940c3"),
    "firstname" : "Louis",
    "lastname" : "Herve",
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610024b189c5b829e72940c4"),
    "firstname" : "Paulette",
    "lastname" : "Besnard",
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610024d989c5b829e72940c5"),
    "firstname" : "Christophe",
    "lastname" : "Pichon",
},
```

As :

- Louis has 2/3 (signed/signable) documents
- Paulette has 1/3
- Christophe 0/3

So I need to sort the documents by signatures and retrieve the users who signed the most documents.

An idea on how to perform this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "signed the most documents" means max number of signed documents or highest percentage of documents signed? i.e. 2/6 or 1/2 which one should win

Comment: what have you tried so far? and where are you stuck? what issues are you facing?

Comment: Hi,
@sagar-dhandhukiya gave me exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query on your collection

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "firstname": "$firstname",
        "lastname": "$lastname",
        "signed": { // Count will be stored in "signed" field
            "$size": { // Get size of filtered documents
                "$filter": { // Filter out signed documents
                    "input": "$documents", "as": "item", "cond": { "$eq": ["$$item.signed", true] }
                }
            }
        },
        "signable": { // Count will be stored in "signable" field
            "$size": { // Get size of filtered documents
                "$filter": { // Filter out signable documents
                    "input": "$documents", "as": "item", "cond": { "$eq": ["$$item.signable", true] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": { // sorting users who signed the most documents
        "signed": -1,
        "signable": -1
    }
}]);
```